# C: How to shmat a struct?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, shared-memory

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct data {
  int code;
  char name[25], fnum[8];
};
```

Then I try to use it as a shared memory like this:

```
int dataSID = shmget(100002, sizeof(struct data), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

and attach it like this:

```
struct data *com = shmat(dataSID, 0, 0);
```

And finally I try filling the values likes this:

```
(*com).code = 1;
scanf("%s", (*com).name);
```

And I get segmentation fault on the `scanf`.

What am I doing wrong?

Does `shmat` properly allocate memory for the struct?

Comment: And shmget succeeds I assume?

Comment: Please show a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org). Your code works in a small program I constructed provided the `scanf` does not overrun the 25-byte buffer (including terminal null). If `scanf` is processing more than 24 characters, then you overrun the buffer.

Comment: @netcoder: note that the OP declared `name` as an array, not as a pointer.

Comment: Ok, the given piece of code seems to work in a new empty program. It does not in the context of my original program though, I will investigate and back with the updated code.

Comment: You should specify a width for your string in `scanf`, e.g.: `scanf("%.24s", com->name)` to prevent buffer overruns (which is likely your problem).

Comment: I've found the problem and I feel really stupid. The attached shared memory was never detached in my program, so when I modified the struct (added fnum member) it became bigger than the original allocated memory.

Comment: @Tony: Try adding you insights as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for character arrays you can always use **strcpy()** or **strncpy()**. Of which strncpy() is recommended which helps to avoid buffer overflow.